# Browserify/Reactify - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, browserify, reactify

I'm trying to abstract my code and I have the following two files in the following structure

```
main.js
  components
  - parent.js
```

main.js

```
require('./components/Parent');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

components/Parent.js

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Parent',
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div> This is the parent page. </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="app">  
</div>
```

I run the following -

```
browserify -t reactify main.js -o main_js.js
```

And this is the javascript it creates

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
require('./components/Parent');

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Parent, null),
    document.getElementById('content')
);

},{"./components/Parent":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var Parent = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Parent',
  render: function(){
    return (
      React.createElement("div", null, 
        React.createElement("div", null, " This is the parent page. ")
      )
    )
  }
});

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

Running the page complains on line 5 which is `React.createElement(Parent, null),`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Parent is not defined
```

But as you can see the file is loaded, so why is it not finding it in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `require('./components/Parent');` to `var Parent = require('./components/Parent');`

You need to specify the name of the variable it's assigned to. Also, if you're placing them in different modules, you need to export the module.

```
// in ./components/Parent
module.exports = Parent;
```

Comment: It looks like he's just creating the Parent in the global scope of the module, meaning it will probably run whenever it is required. This still makes it a scope issue, but maybe with a different solution.

Comment: @shennan It's in a separate module. Browserify bundles separate modules using CommonJS format. So the module has to be exported and imported using those semantics.

Comment: Yes exactly, you're unedited question did not include the export code. Now it does. I commented before the edit. I'm pretty sure you saw it though. :-)